# Magento image upload not working even after giving all folders 777 permissions

Tags: error, image, image-upload

I am unable to upload images in magento admin panel , getting error "Destination folder is not writable or doen't exist". Recently moved all files from one hosting to another. Any solution for this?

Comment: What sort of hosting package do you have? If it includes support might be worth asking them about the current permissions.

Comment: We have two websites hosted on same server and we have all permissions to upload a file  and even though files are not uploading

Answer (score 16):

In your project open the file `lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php` and put a `Mage::log()` inside the `save()` function.

```
public function save($destinationFolder, $newFileName = null)
{
    $this->_validateFile();

    if ($this->_allowCreateFolders) {
        $this->_createDestinationFolder($destinationFolder);
    }

    if (!is_writable($destinationFolder)) {
        // Put a mage::log() and check what is the folder magento is looking for.
        Mage::log($destinationFolder);
        throw new Exception('Destination folder is not writable or does not exists.');
    }
    ...
}
```

From the log you can find out the folder which Magento is looking for. And then check permissions for that folder.

Comment: Thank you so much i forgetted to give file permission to Media/tmp/category/product, and after giving the file permission to that folder the problem has resolved

Comment: Glad to hear your problem was solved. If this was helpful solve the issue please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Magento 2

I get the same error on Magento 2, and this is the file where the error come from in this case:

`vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php`

At line `256` you can temporarily place this code to get the unwritable/unexisting folder:

```
if( !is_writable($destinationFolder) ) {
    // throw new Exception('Destination folder is not writable or does not exists.');
    throw new Exception($destinationFolder);
}
```

---

Otherwise, check if these folders exists and that are writable by the web server:

- `pub/media/catalog/`
- `pub/media/catalog/category`
- `pub/media/catalog/product`
- `pub/media/images`
- `pub/media/wysiwyg/`

Answer (score 3):

For what its worth I've had this issue a few times and have forgotten that it's usually the image file itself, not the server after verifying permissions and all that. It still wouldn't upload the image because it was too large, either in dimensions or in filesize.

The solutions for me are to:

- Scale down a HIGH-REZ photo prior to upload.
- Increase magento Maximum resolution or upload image `System > Catalog > Product Image`
- increase your server's PHP filesize limit with .htaccess or config see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292687/upload-6-mb-image-in-magento

Answer (score 3):

For my the problem was solved by making

> pub/media/tmp

writable by the web server

The next folders under "pub/media" directory also are writables

```
- banners
- catalog
- images
- wysiwyg
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the media folder media/tmp/catalog/product exist "and make that directory writable by your webserver"

Comment: Instead of setting the permission to `777`, it's better to say "and make that directory writable by your webserver". The idea is that there is no need to give every single user write access just so that your webserver can write images. (I'm not the one who downvoted, but just in case you were wondering, this is most likely the reason why)

Comment: yes of course ;)

Answer (score 2):

Kindly check **media** folder having **777** permission.If you are enable the compilation mode means also check **includes** folder having **777** permission.

After giving 777 permission to those folders issue resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the expired certificate from the Plesk administration (it was my case).

I tried the steps above, but it did not work. From there I tried to access the files through FileZilla to give the permissions at once to all folders, hence an error message about the expired certificate. It is not the SSL certificate of the store itself, but the administration of Plesk. I created a new self-signed certificate, applied its Plesk administration and everything went back to normal.

This worked for me. I leave here my contribution.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug in Magento](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5359) for file upload when your magento DocumentRoot on vhost is **properly** set for

```
/path/to/magento/pub
```

Instead of (deprecated)

```
/path/to/magento
```

Uploader tries to create files in

```
/path/to/magento/pub/pub/your_upload_dir
```

Note that location **pub** goes twice.
They told they will fix it in 2.2.0+ but in 2.2.1 this problem still appear.